# How to determine XY of resized image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bitmap loaded into an ImageView dynamically and am using the FitCenter attribute to resize to the users screen.

How do I go about finding the starting X,Y (Left, Top) of the actual image after it's been sized to fit the screen?

Please see annotated attached sample image, in this case I'm looking for the X,left of the bitmap.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I think this actually may do the trick for me without additional computations.
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/white_balance"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/pichost" />

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me without additional computations:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgDisplay" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:contentDescription="@string/white_balance"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/pichost" />
```